# public objects and use of property

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties, instance-variables

I'm a bit confused; if an object is declared in the .h file it is considered automatically as "public" right? We use a `@property` in the .h file, however, to edit them? This is where I don't understand: we use the getter/setter for private objects, so why do we use the `@property` for objects declared in the .h file and thus considered as "public"?

Second thing, I found this example: I don't understand why we use a `@synthesize` for `primaryKey` in this code: http://staging.icodeblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/9-todom1.png
and why we don't use a `@property` for the `database` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not correct that if an object (ivar) is declared in a .h file, then it is public. It is only if getter/setter methods are provided, otherwise it is not.

Indeed, the `@property`/`@synthesize` directives are facilities meant to declare and define default getter/setter methods. So, instead of writing them yourself, you just use the directives.

It is also worth noting that declaring properties you get the possibility of using the dot notation to refer properties of your objects. And also that they clarify a lot, thanks to the `retain`/`assign`/`copy` specifiers, how memory is meant to be managed for that properties. (And, of course, `@synthesize` will just do that correctly for you).

About your sample, in fact, whether an ivar is associated to a property or not is a design choice. Possibly, you just reconsider the assumption that ivars declared in .h files are public by defaults, and it will become clearer. In other words: `primaryKey` is public, `database` is not.

A very nice tutorial can be found [here](http://theocacao.com/document.page/516/) but also do not forget [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1).

EDIT:

about your question from the comment section:

it is not necessary that every ivar has a property, nor that it has getter/setter in order to be used inside of that class implementation.

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject {
    AnotherClass* _anotherClassObj;
    AThirdClass* _aThirdClassObj;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) AnotherClass* anotherClassObj;
@end
```

So, here you have two ivars; only one has got a `@property` declaration. In your .m file you may have, e.g.

```
@implementation SomeClass;
@synthesize anotherClassObj = _anotherClassObj;

- (void)initWithClasses:(AnotherClass*)obj1 and:(AThirdClass*)obj2 {
   .....
   self.anotherClassObj = obj1;
   _aThirdClassObj = obj2;
   ...
}

....
@end
```

In this code:

1. `@synthesize` will provide implementation for getter/setter for `anotherClassObj` so you can use syntax: `self.anotherClassObj = obj1`; that syntax can be used equally from inside and outside the class implementation;
2. when you have no getter/setter (either auto-generated or custom) you can assign directly to an ivar by using the syntax `_aThirdClassObj = obj2;`, with the semantics of simple pointer copy; anyway, `_aThirdClassObj` will not accessible from outside that class;
3. furthermore, `@property ... anotherClassObj` notwithstanding, you can still refer `_anotherClassObj` directly in your .m file, like in `_anotherClassObj = xxx`, bypassing getter/setter, if you ever need it.

One thing you should have clear is that getter/setter are not only a way to make an ivar "public". They also play an important role in managing the retain count (depending on which specifier you choose among retain/assign/copy in the property declaration). So, in `self.anotherClassObj = obj1;` above, `obj1` is assigned to `_anotherClassObj` and it is also retained (and if `_anotherClassObj` was previously pointing to an object, that object will be sent a  `release`). Raw ivar assignment does not provide that kind of facility.

In my opinion, the retain count management feature of properties is far more important than visibility for deciding whether I use a property or not.

Comment: thanks sergio, so every ivar in the .h file, must have a property, if we want to use it in the .m file and put an "=" sign after it (which means we would use the setter)? or can we find in a code where ivars do not take the property and synthesize thing?

Comment: @Paul #2. Try reading [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17).

Comment: @sergio : thanks sergio for the edit! ok, so this is for "objects" like AnotherClass* _anotherClassObj, but we'll never see a "property" for an integer or any other primitive ? And, except the retain thing, is it common to see an object with no use of "property" ? Thanks again

Comment: @Paul: you can surely have properties for primitive types. They have the copy semantics by default and you don't need specify whether it is  retain/assign/copy. As to if it is common, you can do in general whatever makes sense to your app, but I think that properties are so useful for readability (let alone correctness) that it is hard not wanting to use them. On the other hand, if I find a class that does not use properties at all, I would see no problem with it.

Answer (score 2):

Not everything in the header is public, by default ivars (items in the { }) are @protected. The purpose of the @property is data encapsulation. @synthesize or @dynamic is used for declaring the way you want to implement your property and one or the other is necessary to prevent crashes and warnings.

Resources:
[Defining Classes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html)        @protected, @package, @private, @public reference
[Declared Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html)   @property reference